# saving dynamic gridview textbox values and selection values to database in 3 tier architecture

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server-2012, data-controls

i have a page where a gridview is generated dynamically based on dropdown selections,

i was able to generate textbox controls in desired column and insert data to it and able to display data in same textbox on postback/save button click

i am facing issues while saving values to database,

i am able to save textbox values, and id of parameters generated in gridview  to two string variable using , delimeter,

i have used a split function to split values in string in my stored procedure, my SP executed without giving any errors but database is not getting updated
using sqlhelper classes, delegate

can some one help me find my mistake

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_SaveShpValues]
    @shpVals varchar(max),
    @user varchar(30),
    @qdmt decimal(8,3),
    @qwmt decimal(8,3),
    @moisture decimal(8,3),
    @valwith int,
    @strAnal varchar(30),
    @status int out,
    @vesId int,
    @sDate varchar(50),
    @paramId varchar(max),
    @intAnalysisId int,
    @grade int
AS
declare @varvaltime varchar
```

BEGIN

```
set @varvaltime= sysdatetime()
insert into TRAN_SHIPMENT_VALUES (Value,Shp_Parameter_Id,SailDate,Vessel_Id,Analysis_Id,Valuewith,Grade,Last_Updated_By,IsActive,IsDeleted)
select Value.Value, Shp_Parameter_Id.Shp_Parameter_Id,@sDate SailDate , @vesId Vessel_Id ,@intAnalysisId Analysis_Id ,@valwith Valuewith,@grade Grade,@user Last_Updated_By,IsActive=1,IsDeleted=0
from (SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) RowNo,cast (Item as decimal) Value FROM dbo.SplitString(@shpVals, ',')  ) Value,
     (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) RowNo,Item Shp_Parameter_Id FROM dbo.SplitString( @paramId, ',') ) Shp_Parameter_Id 
where  Shp_Parameter_Id.RowNo=Value.RowNo
```

END
i tried to cast the varchar as decimal as below

> Blockquote

(SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) RowNo,cast (Item as decimal) Value FROM dbo.SplitString(@shpVals, ',')  ) Value

```
--IN MY BLL--
public static int SaveShpValues( string shpVals, string user, out int status, int intAnalysisId, int valwith, decimal qdmt, decimal qwmt, decimal moisture, string strDate, string strAnal, int vesId, string paramId, int grade)
   {
       int intStatus = 0;
       intStatus = TestsDLL.SaveShpValues(shpVals, user, out status, intAnalysisId, valwith, qdmt, qwmt, moisture, strDate, strAnal, vesId, paramId, grade);

       return intStatus;
   }
```

here intStatus is returning 0 in BLL
i am able to pass values to the variables and while debugging i can see these but intStatus is returning 0

--IN MY DATA ACCESS LAYER DLL --

```
public static int SaveShpValues( string shpVals, string user, out int status, int intAnalysisId, int valwith, decimal qdmt, decimal qwmt, decimal moisture, string strDate, string strAnal, int vesId, string paramId, int grade)
   {
       SqlParameter[] arrParam = null;
       try
       {
           arrParam = new SqlParameter[13];


           arrParam[0] = new SqlParameter("@shpVals", SqlDbType.VarChar);
           arrParam[0].Value = shpVals;

           arrParam[1] = new SqlParameter("@user", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30);
           arrParam[1].Value = user;

           arrParam[2] = new SqlParameter("@qdmt", SqlDbType.Decimal);
           arrParam[2].Value = qdmt;

           arrParam[3] = new SqlParameter("@qwmt", SqlDbType.Decimal);
           arrParam[3].Value = qwmt;

           arrParam[4] = new SqlParameter("@moisture", SqlDbType.Decimal);
           arrParam[4].Value = moisture;

           arrParam[5] = new SqlParameter("@valwith", SqlDbType.Int);
           arrParam[5].Value = valwith;

           arrParam[6] = new SqlParameter("@strAnal", SqlDbType.VarChar);
           arrParam[6].Value = strAnal;

           arrParam[7] = new SqlParameter("@status", SqlDbType.Int);
           arrParam[7].Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

           arrParam[8] = new SqlParameter("@vesId", SqlDbType.Int);
           arrParam[8].Value = vesId;

           arrParam[9] = new SqlParameter("@strDate", SqlDbType.VarChar);
           arrParam[9].Value =  strDate;

           arrParam[10] = new SqlParameter("@paramId", SqlDbType.VarChar);
           arrParam[10].Value = paramId;

           arrParam[11] = new SqlParameter("@intAnalysisId", SqlDbType.Int);
           arrParam[11].Value = intAnalysisId;

           arrParam[12] = new SqlParameter("@grade", SqlDbType.Int);
           arrParam[12].Value = grade;


           SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(ConnectionString, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "SP_SaveShpValues", arrParam);

           if (arrParam[7].Value != DBNull.Value) // status
               status = Convert.ToInt32(arrParam[7].Value);
           else
               status = 0;
           return status;
       }
       catch (Exception objEx)
       {
           ErrorLogDAL objErrorLogManager = new ErrorLogDAL();
           objErrorLogManager.AddErrorLog(objEx);
           objErrorLogManager = null;

           status = 0; return status;
       }
       finally
       {
           arrParam = null;
       }
   }
```

-- IN CODE BEHIND -

```
public void Saveval(string AnalysisName)
   {
       int vesId = Convert.ToInt32(ddlVesselList.SelectedValue);
       DateTime.TryParseExact(txtsaildate.Text.ToString(), "dd-MM-yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out saildt);
       string strDate = saildt.Date.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy");

       decimal qdmt = Decimal.Parse(lblDMTvalue.Text);
       decimal qwmt = Decimal.Parse(txtwmt.Text);
       decimal moist = Decimal.Parse(txtmoist.Text);
       int status = 0;
       int valid = 1;
       SaveShipValues_delegate del = null;
       int analysis_Id = Convert.ToInt32(ddlanalysis.SelectedValue);
       selction = Convert.ToInt32(ddlvalueswith.SelectedValue);

       DataTable dtparam = TestsBLL.GetParamtoTable(analysis_Id, selction);
       foreach (DataRow drparam in dtparam.Rows)
       {
           paramId = Convert.ToInt32(drparam["Parameter_Id"]) + "," + paramId;
       }
       try
       {
           pIndx = 0;
           if (AnalysisName == "xxx")
           {
               foreach (GridViewRow gr in gridshipval.Rows)
               {
                   TextBox txtbox = (TextBox)gr.FindControl("txtbox'"+pIndx+"'");
                   if (txtbox != null)
                   {
                       string strRegExp = "^([0-9]{1,25})?(.[0-9]{0,8})?$";
                       txtbox.CausesValidation = true;
                       txtbox.MaxLength = 6;
                       if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(txtbox.Text, strRegExp))
                       {

                           shpVals = txtbox.Text + "," + shpVals;
                           pIndx++;
                       }
                       else
                       {
                           txtbox.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                           lblMsg.Text = "Please give only numbers";
                           shpVals = "";
                           valid = 0;
                           break;
                       }

                   }
                   else break;
               }
           }
```

else if (AnalysisName == "yyy") ----

```
string strAnal = ddlanalysis.SelectedItem.ToString();
               int grade = Convert.ToInt32(ddlgrade.SelectedValue);

               del = new SaveShipValues_delegate(TestsBLL.SaveShipValues);
               IAsyncResult res = null;
               res = del.BeginInvoke(shpVals, Convert.ToString(Session["UserName"]), out status, Convert.ToInt32(ddlanalysis.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(ddlvalueswith.SelectedValue), qdmt, qwmt, moist, strDate, strAnal, vesId,  paramId,grade, null, null);
               lblMsg.Text = "Values Saved Successfully, Please check updated values after 2 minutes.";
```

can someone help to find and rectify my mistake